# F# type definition using `of` keyword

Tags: f#

Let me state that I am very green in F# (but 4 years experience in C#). I wanted to start learning F# and I was following the TryFSharp.org tutorials. I came to the point of the [computation expressions](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/advanced-programming#computation-expressions) but things weren't exactly clear. So I started to google it. I came across **[another tutorial / article](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/)** which explained it a lot better in the first example (the logging example). But then I read on and came to the second example; I cannot follow the flow of the code or how it is supposed to work, perhaps because I don't understand the definition of the `State` type:

```
type State<'a, 's> = State of ('s -> 'a * 's)
```

I have worked with a few simple types in F# already, I have seen `struct`, `class`, `record` but I have no clue how to read this type or what it is supposed to do. I also can't figure out what the `of` keyword is doing in there.

So my question is: what does this type definition do / what does the `of` keyword in it do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code defines a [discriminated union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) type named `State` whose only constructor is also named `State` and takes an argument of type `'s -> 'a * 's`. The `of` keyword separated the constructor name from its argument type.

So basically it says that a `State` is a function of type `'s -> 'a * 's`, but you need to use the `State` constructor to create a `State` and thus have to write `let myState = State someFunction` rather than `let myState = someFunction`.

Answer (score 6):

As already stated, `State` is a single case discriminated union type. A two-case union type would look like:

```
type Multi = 
  | First of name:string
  | Second of number:int
```

One way to think of this is `Multi` as a base class and `First` and `Second` as subclasses where `First` requires a string in the constructor and `Second` requires an int. This is a very powerful construct not available in C#. It is powerful because you can pattern match of values of this type and the compiler will force you to handle every case.

A single case union is helpful as a wrapper of another type. In your example, the `State` type wraps a function from type `'s` to a pair (C# tuple) `'a * 's`. It turns out that this is a very interesting type because it forms a monad and as a result you get all sorts of functions around it. For example, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eulerfx/9808911) shows how the `State` monad can be used to implement functional random value generators.

Comment: As SynerCoder is new to F#, it might also be worth mentioning that - in constrast to your base class/sub class analogy - union cases (`First` and `Second` in the example) are *not* (sub-)types.

Comment: True - there is no subtype relation defined on ASTs at all. DUs are implemented using subtypes in the CLR though.